# SilverLight Datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am building a timemanagement system, where im using a Datagrid to list tasks / days, so you can register how much time you spend on a given task on a given day.

What i would like, is to do a summary at the bottom of each day.

```
| Tasks  | Moanday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| Task 1 |   1     |   1     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
| Task 2 |   2     |   0     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
| Task 3 |   3     |   2     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
         |   6     |   3     |    0      |    0     |   0    |
```

Does anyone have any hints, on how to add a footer like effect, like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the agDataGridSuite from DevExpress. It supports summaries. They offer this grid as a free download. See [link text](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Grid/)